# Options for sending SQL data from server A to Server B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL database that has values. I need to replicate some of those values on another remote server SQL. 
Not all values, Just columns 1,5,9 for example, and have this happen every 60 minutes. 
I have the tables on server A being pushed in from another application. 
I then want Server B to either GET them or maybe I POST them? Not sure. Help/guidance please. 
Both servers Linux/LAMP. 
Is A send to B safer? I have no idea. Which is easiest for novice to setup. 
Thankyou.

Comment: " Both servers Linux/LAMP" and a Tag `sql-server`?

Comment: New to this sorry. Centos host. MySql.

Comment: I edited your question and removed the sql-server tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Replication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402794/mysql-replication)

Answer (score 0):

If you have sql-server, you may use replication, if you are using mysql (not clear due to tags), you may use [federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/federated-storage-engine.html), which will do the job for you.

In the latter case, a locally issued SQL will be passed to the original table on the other (remote) server, so that's not quite a replication, but its not clear whether this is actually needed.

Comment: I dont think its SQL server. Just Centos with MYsql database on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to take the data from one SQl server to another Sql Server just add the linked server, Using the below link add the linked server.
http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server